# Solr: Set field boost at index-time with DataImportHandler

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4, solr-boost

I need to set a field boost at index-time with DataImportHandler.
I tried to do somethings like this:

```
<entity name="places"  
    query="Select id, boost, text from table">
<field name="id"    column="id" />
<field name="boost"     column="boost"  />
<field name="1_text"  column="text"  boost="${boost}" />
</entity>
```

but it doesn't works. That is the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${boost}"
```

An other approch that i did is to try also to use a script (an transformer, but i don't know the syntax to set the boost at field):

```
<script><![CDATA[
                function addfield(row){
                    var fieldName = row.get('id') + "_text"
                    row.put(fieldName, row.get('text'));
                    return row;
                }
            ]]></script>
```

Please, Do you have any suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no support for dynamic boosting per field in the transformer, unless you specify a static boost value in the entity. There is a way to set a document boost, but it will affect all the fields in the doc like:

```
 row.put('$docBoost', row.get('boost'));
```

If this is not what you need I would recommend to look at the [query time boosting](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#Field_Based_Boosting) since you already store the "boost" field.

Comment: Unfortunatly i need to set a different boost for field