# How to Associate tags with documents in solr?

Tags: search, solr, lucene, indexing, search-engine

I have URLS with tags associated with them in my database, like below  
`url : tag1(score) tag2(score)`

eg:

`www.w3schools.com: html(4.5) php(3.5) etc..`
`www.php.net: php(5) etc...`

now, i'd like to store these links in solr with the weighted tags, and make them searchable,

How can this be done in solr?
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use index-time per-field boost, like so:

```
<add>
  <doc>
    <field name="URL">stackoverflow.com</field>
    <field name="tag" boost="11.0">html</field>
    <field name="tag" boost="9.0">php</field>
  </doc>
</add>
```

The documentation is available [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes_for_.22field.22).

Comment: right, this is what i wanted. the URLs and tags are stored in mysql and imported to solr, do you know how to assign boost scores during this process, rather than individual processing of solr documents after importing?

Comment: You cannot assign per-field boost at index-time if you are using the DataImportHandler to import your data from MySQL. See this previous StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680563/solr-set-field-boost-at-index-time-with-dataimporthandler.

If the boost value is always the same for each tag, you could boost you result at query time: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_change_the_score_of_a_document_based_on_the_.2Avalue.2A_of_a_field_.28say.2C_.22popularity.22.29